# Add space between the menu and the content on Woocommerce products pages?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors

On my WooCommerce [**web site**](https://dev.evolutionaryeducation.org/product/practicing-eternity-vol-i/), there is a missing space between the main menu and the content on 'product' pages.

I have found any settings to ajust that. I'm not familiar with PHP to the level where I can open files in the Wordpress editor and make changes without breaking something.

How can I add space between menu and content on "product" pages?
Please help me understand how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need to add in your theme `styles.css` file the following CSS rules:

```css
.woocommerce-page .sections_group {
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.woocommerce .sections_group,
.woocommerce-page.woocommerce-account .sections_group {
    margin-top: 66px;
}
```

This will add the necessary space between the header menu and the content:

- The first rule target cart and checkout pages
- The second one target Woocommerce archives pages (as shop), single product pages and account pages

You can fine tune the space changing the number of pixels for each…

Answer (score -1):

use this keyword `&nbsp`  with any tag like pagragraph tag or div tag this will create a non-break but a new line